# Don't work cleaned_data in Django

Tags: django, validation, cleaned-data

This is my code:

```
class HighschoolForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Highschool
        fields = ['id', 'dni', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'country', 'phone', 'mobile', 'mail', 'website', 'contact', 'entrydate']

    def clean_mail(self):
        mail = self.cleaned_data.get('mail')   #self.cleaned_data['mail']
        mail_base, proveedor = mail.split('@')
        dominio, extension = proveedor.split('.')
        if extension == 'ptn':
            raise forms.ValidationError('Does not allow Pluton mails....')
        return self.cleaned_data['mail']
```

However when I introduced data in ModelForm in the admin view a mail with a "ptn" extension, Django doesn't refused the data and record in the database. 
Which is the problem? I read de Django 2.0 documentation and I don't find the failure.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using this form in the admin? How? Show your ModelAdmin class.

Comment: Yes, I use the form in admin.

Comment: from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Highschool
from .forms import HighschoolForm
class AdminHighschool(admin.ModelAdmin):

 list_display = ['id', 'dni', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'country', 'phone', 'mobile', 'mail', 'website', 'contact', 'entrydate',]
 formhs = HighschoolForm
 
 list_display_links = ['id', 'dni', 'name']
 list_editable = ['address', 'phone', 'mobile', 'mail', 'website', 'contact']

 list_filter = ['city','country']

 search_fields = ['name']
admin.site.register(Highschool, AdminHighschool)

Comment: You should have put that as an edit to the question. Why are you setting `formhs`? You need to set `form`.